# OutOfMemoryError() in julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to initialize a grid in Julia but I get an out of memory error when I try to read from stdin(commented out line). If I assign the size manually, it runs fine.

I added the print statement at the bottom to be sure I'm reading in correctly and it gives me the right output. I've searched all over but cant seem to be able to find a solution.

This isnt the full program I intend to write, but I want to be certain that reading in and writing out work properly before I proceed further.

I've attached my code below. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

```
function main()
    i::UInt32 = 0
    j::UInt32 = 0
    interval::UInt32 = 0

    gridDifference::Float32 = 0.0
    stableValue::Float32 = 0.0
    MIN_FIXED_TEMP::Float32 = 0.0

    counter::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)
    NUM_ROWS::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)
    NUM_COLUMNS::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)
    EPSILON_VALUE::Float32 = read(STDIN, Int32)

    #initialGrid::Array{Float32,2} = read(STDIN, Float32, NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS)
    initialGrid::Array{Float32,2} = read(STDIN, Float32, 1024,1024)


    write(STDOUT, counter)
    write(STDOUT, EPSILON_VALUE)
    write(STDOUT, NUM_ROWS)
    write(STDOUT, NUM_COLUMNS)
    write(STDOUT, newGrid)

    print(STDERR,NUM_COLUMNS)

end

main()
```

Part 2

I got the code working, but it only solves square grids in the correct iteration. If the number of rows and columns are not equal, it solves in more iterations than it should. Any Idea what I'm overlooking?

```
function main()
    gridDifference::Float32 = 0.0
    stableValue::Float32 = 100.0        
    counter::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)
    EPSILON_VALUE::Float32 = read(STDIN, Float32)
    NUM_ROWS::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)
    NUM_COLUMNS::Int32 = read(STDIN, Int32)

    initialGrid::Array{Float32,2} = read(STDIN, Float32, NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS)
    newGrid = Array{Float32,2}(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLUMNS)
    for i=2:NUM_COLUMNS - 1, j=2:NUM_ROWS - 1
        newGrid[j,i] = 50.0
    end

    while stableValue > EPSILON_VALUE
        stableValue = 0.0
        for i in 2:NUM_COLUMNS - 1, j in 2:NUM_ROWS - 1
            newGrid[j,i] = (initialGrid[j,i - 1] + initialGrid[j,i + 1] + initialGrid[j + 1,i] + initialGrid[j - 1,i]) / 4          
            gridDifference = abs(newGrid[j,i] - initialGrid[j,i])           
            if gridDifference > EPSILON_VALUE
                    stableValue = gridDifference
            end
        end
        initialGrid = copy(newGrid)
        if stableValue > EPSILON_VALUE
            counter +=1
        end

    end
    write(STDOUT, counter)
    write(STDOUT, EPSILON_VALUE)
    write(STDOUT, NUM_ROWS)
    write(STDOUT, NUM_COLUMNS)
    write(STDOUT, newGrid)

    println(STDERR, counter)
    println(STDERR, EPSILON_VALUE)
    println(STDERR, NUM_ROWS)
    println(STDERR, NUM_COLUMNS)
```

end

main()

Comment: use `https://github.com/JuliaComputing/JuliaDB.jl` Julia already has some issues with large arrays. Try smaller numbers while debugging

Comment: "Julia already has some issues with large arrays." No that's not true? Do you have a reference for that claim? They're the same layout as C or NumPy arrays with an 80 byte type tag IIRC, so you'll only have an issue there if you would've had an issue in any other language. JuliaDB doesn't apply here since it's talking about in core arrays, not out-of-core data structures. If there is a bug to work through here it would be in the input, as demonstrated by the fact that it works if the size is manually put in.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you getting your input from the canonical binary representation? It should match the output of something like `write(STDOUT, rand(5,5))`, and it won't be numbers. Even if that works out, for array-based IO it's usually better to use a format designed for it though, like [JLD2.jl](https://github.com/simonster/JLD2.jl), [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl), [BSON.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/BSON.jl), or [JSON2.jl](https://github.com/quinnj/JSON2.jl). These days I prefer JLD2 and BSON. These can be more maintainable than binary inputs.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Rackauckas. I'm new to Julia and this is my first Julia program. I'm expected to read and write in binary though. your post gave me the idea to write out all the parameters and it seems the NUM_ROWS being read in is actually a very large number. I changed the order of read in;s, and I was able to figure it out.